# How to join the WordPress table with other tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on search functionality. I have to search the data from `service_name` and  `article1` table. So I use an inner join to get the data from both the tables.`service_name` and `article1` are connected using `ID` so I can use inner join easily to get the data.

I am using the below query for search and it's working

```
SELECT a.slug_url, a.heroheading, a.herodescription, a.headingone, a.description, a.service_id, s.service_name, s.service_slug FROM service_name as s join article1 as a  on s.id =a.service_id WHERE a.heroheading LIKE ? OR a.herodescription LIKE ? OR a.headingone LIKE ? OR a.description LIKE ? OR s.service_name LIKE ? order by heroheading ASC
```

Now I have to add one more table called `wp_posts`. But this table is not linked with any table. I have to use this query with my search query

`SELECT post_content,post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status="publish"`

I tried below query but it's not working

```
SELECT a.slug_url, a.heroheading, a.herodescription, a.headingone, a.description, a.service_id, s.service_name, s.service_slug, wp.post_content,wp.post_title FROM service_name as s join article1 as a  on s.id =a.service_id join wp_posts as wp WHERE a.heroheading LIKE ? OR a.herodescription LIKE ? OR a.headingone LIKE ? OR a.description LIKE ? OR s.service_name LIKE ? OR wp.post_content LIKE ? OR wp.post_title LIKE ? order by heroheading ASC
```

What I want, When the user searches anything in the search then it will check from all 3 tables and if found anything then display.

Would you help me out with this?
I am sharing the table image here

**article1**
[image]

**service_name**
[image]

**wp_posts**
[image]

I added the table here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLsJXncQ4i2Uvfppap6gLf/0

Would you help me out in this?

**Full PHP function here**

```
function search($conn){
$output='';
$param = "%{$_POST['searchquery']}%";

$query="SELECT a.slug_url, a.heroheading, a.herodescription, a.headingone, a.description, a.service_id, s.service_name, s.service_slug, wp.post_content,wp.post_title FROM service_name as s join article1 as a  on s.id =a.service_id join wp_posts as wp WHERE a.heroheading LIKE ? OR a.herodescription LIKE ? OR a.headingone LIKE ? OR a.description LIKE ? OR s.service_name LIKE ? OR wp.post_content LIKE ? OR wp.post_title LIKE ?  order by heroheading ASC";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $param, $param,$param, $param,$param,$param, $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($slug_url, $heroheading, $herodescription, $headingone, $description, $service_id, $service_name, $service_slug, $post_content,$post_title); 

$output ='<div id="searchList"><ul class="searchrecordList">';
if($stmt->num_rows >0){
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $output .='//search record here';
}
}
else{
    $output .='<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Search result not found</a></li>';
}
$output .='</ul></div>';
echo $output;
$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: add to *join wp_posts as wp**  a ON clause, so that mysql knows which rows to join.

Comment: @nbk, Yes I used  join wp_posts as wp but haven't use ON clause. Because I don't know what I have to use with ON clause?

Comment: a cross join combines all rows from the left side with all rows from the right site. I beleive no one can help you in you quest, to find a commen denominator between two table or even tree. even when you posted all tables with data, the logic is in your programming.

Comment: @nbk, Do you know any online tool where I can upload my table to show you?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk and https://www.db-fiddle.com  the latter you have to click update to get a unique link

Comment: @nbk, I am using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @nbk, I added the image screenshot in the question. Please check it once if it can help to solve this issue.

Comment: @nbk, I added 2 tables here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLsJXncQ4i2Uvfppap6gLf/0

Comment: wp_post is ,missing

Comment: @nbk, That is WordPress table, I am trying to add it but getting error

Comment: as far as i can see, all wp_posts  where made by the teacher or by the servce_id as author_id

Comment: @nbk, No, any once can post the data.teacher  and author_id are not linked with wp_post table

Comment: article1 table and service_name table are linked using servce_id. wp_posts table no connected with any of the table

Comment: i can see that, then create a connection between article and wp_posts.. I hope that a there ia a connection.

Comment: @nbk, No, I can't create. Because wp_posts are my blog. service_name and article1 are my PHP tables wp_posts are my WordPress table. All the tables are in single database